# Returning a filename from a ksh function gives a 'bad number' error

Tags: shell, ksh

I have a shell script with a function and when I call the function I am getting a bad number error. In my function I am getting a filename from the database and returning it.  The return gives the 'bad number' error.  Details below:

```
call to GET_MYFILE() :
  GET_MYFILE $jobid
--$job id has the correct number in it

GET_MYFILE()
{
        echo "job id input parameter is : " $1
        curfile=`sqlplus -s /@username<< EOF
        set feed off heading off verify off serveroutput off

        select my_file_name
        from my_table_name
        where jobid=$1;
        exit;
EOF`
        echo "curfile is : " $curfile
        return $curfile
}

-- echo "curfile is : " $curfile - displays correct filename 
--return $curfile gives bad number error.
```

Comment: `return` cannot return arbitrary data, only an integer exit status. Shell functions really aren't very function-like; they are more like small programs.

Comment: `return` to a function is similar to `exit` to a shell script. It sets the status (`$?`) and returns to the caller.

Answer (score 0):

In the Korn Shell syntax, the `return` statement syntax offers only two variants:

- `return`    (and in this case, the returned number is the exit code of the most recently executed command in the function).
- `return n`  (where n is a number between 0 and 255)

In either case, the caller can access the numeric value returned via the `$?` pseudovariable in an assignment or conditional statement.

If you try to return a filename then you should expect "bad number", because a filename string cannot usually be interpreted as a number.